# JScrollPane constructor 'Not supported yet' error

Tags: java, dialog, jframe, jscrollpane

I am trying to create a frame which contains a panel with a scrollable text area as follows.

```
public static void showErrorDialog(String strErrMsg, Exception e) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(strErrMsg);
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(6, 25);
    textArea.setText(getStackTrace(e));
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    pane.add(lbl);
    pane.add(scroll);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, pane, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

I have used an example from a text book as a reference. However I am getting the following error at run-time:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at mypackage.excel.JScrollPane.<init>(JScrollPane.java:16)
```

I am also getting a compile-time error trying to add the scroll pane to the panel:

`no suitable method found for add(JScrollPane)`

Essentially I just want to display an error dialog with the JLabel passed in (`strErrMsg`) and the error stack trace in the `JTextArea`. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is this `mypackage.excel.JScrollPane` class ?

Comment: @Berger That is an excellent question...somehow a new implementation of the `JScrollPane` class had been created. I deleted it and imported javax.swing.JScrollPane and all is working!